# Como eu faria pra mostrar a pessoa logada no topo da lista

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando montar um `SELECT` que exibe a pessoa no topo da lista, fiz assim mais está mostrando ela no final de todos `"SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id != ? DESC"`, vou dar um exemplo, tenho uma div que mostra os nomes das pessoas logadas exemplo `Bruno(eu), maria, rosa, joaquina etc....` quero que mostre o nome da pessoa que está logada sempre acima dos demais como eu montaria esse `select` ?

Comment: Por pessoa logada, você diz apenas você, que está fazendo a consulta enquanto logado? Ou todos os logados no seu sistema?

Comment: todos os logados, por exemplo, ta logado Bruno e Maria, na minha tela mostra eu acima de Maria, e na tela da Maria mostra ela acima de mim, entendeu ?

Comment: Como é identificado que a pessoa está logada dentro da tabela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode utilizar um case.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios 
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN id == ? THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END
```